# How to solve this sum of a recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I've been given the recurrence relation $a_n = na_{n-1}+n^2a_{n-2}$ where $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1$.

I need to find $a_{1000}$.

My understanding is that this is very similar to the Fibonacci sequence. I also believe that I need to derive an explicit formula to find (And be able to express) the answer.

Unfortunately, I have zero idea how to do this and haven't found much that really helps me despite a long search.

Comment: I hope you have a large number library available.  At $n=38, a_{38}\approx 10^{53}$ so if you want it exactly you will need lots of digits.

Comment: An interesting feature about this sequence is that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} = \frac{\sqrt5 -1}{2}$$

Comment: According to my calculations the result is $\,a_{1000} \approx 2.157916788523104\times 10^{2777}.$ I could print all the digits but it would be pointless.

Comment: How did you get the answer?

Comment: I used computer algebra systems Mathematica and PARI/GP. They both gave the same results. Getting numerical results like this is easy.Getting closed forms is harder.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I might go about getting a closed form?

Comment: Why do you need a closed form?